# Versioning and approval of workflow

Tags: java, workflow, jcr

I have a requirement in our project where we have a sequence of operations on the map (we call a plan) from a user and plan goes to a higher officer then he approves or rejects it and comes back to the same user.

1. How can I version the plans
2. How can I do life cycle management of a plan

Please help me, I am new to these kind of requirements. Technologies used are portlets, jsp, jboss server and web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way myself for the above problem.
1. For versioning, I have tried envers by hibernate, which is very interesting and solved my problem.
2. For Approval, I am using jBPM workflow engine for life cycle management.